# How to solve $2f(x)+xf(\frac{1}{x})-2f(|\sqrt2 \sin(\pi(x+\frac{1}{4}))|) = 4 \cos^2 \frac{\pi x}{2}+x\cos\frac{\pi}{x}$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I saw a question today. $$2f(x)+xf(\frac{1}{x})-2f(|\sqrt2 \sin(\pi(x+\frac{1}{4}))|) = 4 \cos^2 \frac{\pi x}{2}+x\cos\frac{\pi}{x}$$

It had options like this (one or more than one may be correct):

A. $f(2) + f(\frac{1}{2}) =1$
B. $f(1)=-1$, but the values of $f(2), f(1/2)$  cannot be determined
C. $f(2) + f (1) = f(\frac{1}{2})$
D. $f(2) + f (1) = 0$

**How to approach these kinds of questions?** I tried putting $\frac{1}{x}$ instead of $x$ but it didn't help.

Is there any way to get the answers other than plugging these values?

The correct options are

> A, C, D

Comment: Take A for instance, it mentions $f(2)$ and $f({1\over 2})$. Have you tried replacing $x$ by $2$ in the equation?

Comment: @Cheese Yes...I got f(1) = 0..What does this mean?

Comment: So let's replace $x=2$ in your equation :

$$2f(2)+2f(\frac{1}{2})-2f(|\sqrt2 \sin(\pi(2+\frac{1}{4}))|) = 4 \cos^2 \frac{2\pi}{2}+2\cos\frac{\pi}{2}$$

which simplifies to $f(\frac{1}{2})=2$, disproving B. Unless I made a mistake.

Comment: @Cheese  do i have to do this for all the options?...I mean if there any other way?

Comment: Unless there's something clever I cannot see, I'd try replacing $x$ with $2,1,{1\over 2}$

Comment: I just realized that I indeed made a mistake in my $x=2$ replacement.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-$|\sqrt 2(\sin (\pi x+\frac {\pi}{4}))|=|\sin \pi x+\cos \pi x|$ it follows
$$2f(x)+xf(\frac 1x)-2f(|\sin \pi x+\cos \pi x|)=4\cos (\frac{\pi x}{2})^2+x\cos(\frac{\pi}{x})$$ Hence $$2f(2)+2f(\frac 12)-2f(|0+1|)=4(-1)^2+2\cdot 0$$
$$f(2)=-f(\frac 12)+f(1)+2$$
Furthermore $$2f(1) +f(\frac 11)-2f(|0-1|)=4(\cos (\frac{\pi}{2}))^2+\cos \pi=0-1$$  $$3f(1)-2f(1)=f(1)=-1 $$

From this I deduced only option B is correct.

Comment: You also proved that A is correct. Since $f(1)=-1$, substitute in $f(2)=-f(\frac 12)+f(1)+2$ and you get $f(2) + f(\frac{1}{2}) =1$

Comment: In fact, if you then replace $x={1\over 2}$ in the original equation, you also get $4f({1\over 2})+f(2)-4f(1)=5$. If you use the fact that $f(1)=-1$, you obtain $4f({1\over 2})+f(2)=1$. Finally, this gives us $f({1\over 2})=0$ and $f(2)=1$. This proves A, C and D and it disproves B.

Comment: But the answer is (A) (C) (D)

Comment: What happen is I have problem to write in English and many times when I end there are answers equal to mine so I have to discard what I did. Writing being in a hurry is not good in maths. Regards.